# How to create new repository via ssh?

Tags: github

I would like to use the opportunity of passwordless access which is provided by ssh keys to create new repositories, instead of opening the browser and logging in git hosting provider by entering username and password each time. How to create new repository via ssh?

Comment: [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: @gnat: it is not about tool, it is about how to create new repository

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: "The tool" is GitHub. This site is about Software Engineering, not tool support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub API does provide a mechanaism for project creation, ***currently in alpha status***.  See https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/#create-a-repository-project

Comment: It is not what I was looking for. Your link explains how to do it via http, which requires to enter login and password. Is there any ssh support?

Comment: Are there any git hosting providers which provide ssh access for creating free repositories? It does not have to be github.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko - I have to ask why __create__ repo via ssh? - It only needs to be done once per repository so is not that much of a hardship, once it is created you have full access via ssh.

Answer (score -1):

I use this `/usr/local/bin/github`

```
#!/bin/dash

# Create a personal access token here
#
#     https://github.com/settings/tokens
#
# and make sure it has the 'repo' scope.

TOKEN=`cat /home/user/github_token`
REPO=$2
curl -s -XPOST -H 'Authorization: token '$TOKEN https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"'$REPO'"}'|egrep -w 'already|"name":'|grep -o '.*[^,]'|cut -d: -f2|perl -pe 's/^ "(.*)"/$1/;s/name already exists on this account/already exists/'|perl -pe "s/$REPO/successfully created/"
```

It is run as `github init myrepo`. It is useful to create and fork projects from CLI.